# How to give source to parameters for Formview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, formview

I have created Formview. and Created Update query and provided parameters manually in SqlDataSource. But I have confusion that how can I provide Source for parameters?

I tried Command and Parameter Editor, but as control I only find Formview2. So, how can I provide source for parameters? Say Source for Param1 = (Formview1.FindControl(textbo1)).text, Param2 =(Formview1.FindControl(textbo2)).text

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind you could try something like this

```
 Dim txtBox as TextBox = Formview1.FindControl("TextBox1").text
 sqlDataSource1.Parameters.Add("@ParameterName", txtBox)
```

This will manually set your parameter @ParameterName = txtBox. SqlDataSource1 will be your existing datasource that you have already created.

Also see here [Cannot Find Control ID in ControlParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386048/cannot-find-control-id-in-controlparameter) for doing this in the markup